# reactjs - Inserting data into tables with props

Tags: reactjs, react-props, devextreme

i am using reactjs. I'm using the devextreme-reactive editable-table component.

I get an error when I want to add the json data I received as an arrayList with this.props.customer.customerDebts.customerAllDebts into the table as follows.

How can I fix this?

https://ibb.co/zrXmz9m

```
 <Paper style={{width: "100%"}}>
        <Grid
          rows={this.props.customerDebts.customerAllDebts.json}
          columns={this.state.columns}
        >
          <EditingState
            onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
            columnExtensions={[
              {columnName: "first_name", editingEnabled:false},
              {columnName: "last_name", editingEnabled:false},
            ]}
          />
          <PagingState
            defaultPageSize={5}
            defaultCurrentPage={5}
          />
          <IntegratedPaging />
          <Table />
          <TableColumnResizing
            defaultColumnWidths={this.state.defaultColumnWidths}
          />
          <TableHeaderRow />
          <PagingPanel
            pageSizes={this.state.pageSizes}
            messages={this.pagingPanelMessages}
          />
          <TableEditRow />
          <TableEditColumn
            showAddCommand
            showEditCommand
            showDeleteCommand
            commandComponent={Command}
          />
          <TableBandHeader
            columnBands={this.state.columnBands}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Paper>
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: I am getting an error like in the picture, I cannot import the data in this.props.customerDebts.customerAllDebts, it gives error.

Comment: please help me.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to conditionally render it if and only if the length of the data is greater than 0.

```
<Paper style={{width: "100%"}}>
{ 
  this.props.customerDebts.customerAllDebts.customerAllDebts.length > 0 &&
  <Grid
  rows={ this.props.customerDebts.customerAllDebts.customerAllDebts }
  columns={this.state.columns}>
}
  <EditingState
    onCommitChanges={this.commitChanges}
    columnExtensions={[
      {columnName: "first_name", editingEnabled:false},
      {columnName: "last_name", editingEnabled:false},
    ]}
  />
```

Comment: I shared all the code because I got an error. can you edit it again

Comment: can you please share me the code sandbox link here, that will give me a clear picture of why you re getting the error?